# How can Aptana help with Netsuite Client Suitescript development?

Tags: netsuite

I found my way here from the 3-years-out-of-date page at http://suitesource.netsuite.com/s.nl/it.A/id.82/.f .  I have the latest eclipse, with the Aptana plugin and the NetSuiteEclipse plugin.

Just exactly what does Aptana do for me?   It's not altogether clear, and it seems Netsuite may have abandoned their end of it.

Answer (score 4):

By far the best environment I have found lately with regards to developing scripts for NetSuite is to just bag the instructions given by NetSuite and go with Aptana Studio 3 (not Eclipse with the Aptana plugin) and then include the NetSuite plugin to allow for direct upload into NS as Jeff mentioned. Aptana Studio is basically just Eclipse for JS and some additional cool features, like built in color themes.

The only other step you need to do (and this is not mentioned in the NS help) is to place SuiteScriptApi.js (and maybe nlapihandler.nl.js) in the root of your main project folder. The above configuration will give you code completion/definition for JavaScript in general and SuiteScript. I forget where I got the files but you can search on SuiteAnswers for them.

The help really needs to be updated to include the changes in IDE's.

Answer (score 1):

The aptana plugin is not Netsuite specific it is a plugin for javascript development and provides code completion for javascript.  The code completion of the netsuite objects is limited.

The netsuite plugin to Eclipse allows you to upload your suitescripts to netsuite directly from eclipse.  However there are some limitations as to the path of the uploaded files that I can't remember at the moment.  It did not allow me to set the paths the way I wanted so I stopped using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Suitecloud IDE.

Created from Eclipse but customized for Netsuite API.

http://elibeltran.com/suitecloud-ide/

Comment: Please update your answer. The provided link is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

About once a year I try Aptana and I end up uninstalling it each time- recently I tried again for my third time and uninstalled it.  In my experience the code completion isn't very good, it doesn't handle complicated inheritance situations, doesn't play well with object literal notation, etc.  I don't have proof and I've uninstalled it so if anyone asks me for specific examples I can't produce them.

I always end up back with Eclipse classic (3.7 I think) and JS Eclipse (which is an abandoned plugin that Adobe bought from [Interakt](http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/) but it still works)  It's fast and has decent code completion.  Is it better than Aptana?  I don't think so, but it's snappier and seems to require less restarts.

I wish I had better experience with Aptana, it makes me nervous that JS Eclipse is a ghost that will disapear here at some point.  I maintain over 48k lines of SuiteScript in our installation, I REALLY could use a better tool!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Visual Studio 11.

It has much better intellisense in my opinion (as long as you configure it with any libraries such as the SuiteScript API.js).  It also works well if you are already used to Visual Studio from .NET development (including SuiteTalk web services).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an IDE but here is some suggestion.

Use a Google Chrome debugger. When you are in Edit mode in a record (example: customer), you can use the suitescript API to get the object-tree, very helpful in developing client-side script in Netsuite and understanding how their API works.